# functional equation

Tags: calculus

> Let $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left[f(xy)+f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right]$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R^{+}}$ such that $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1) = 2.$ Then $f(x)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using Inspection above $f(x)=2\ln(x)$ satisfy the above equation,  but I did not

understand how can I solve it, Help required,  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E$ your functional equation. Hints:

a) Derive E with respect to $y$, and then put $x=1$.

b) Derive E with respect to $x$, and then put $x=1$

c) Find $f^{\prime}(y)$